# JPA DDL-Generation with drop reuses old index

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

we're using JPA and for test reasons have drop-and-create-tables as ddl-generation mode. However, this leads to some odd behaviour when restarting the application:

1. We run the application once and generate some data. E.g. we create 70 entites, which get ascending IDs from 1 to 70 -> works fine
2. We restart the application, thus the tables are dropped and recreated -> works fine
3. When we now create the data again and here it gets odd: The IDs for the new entities start at 31 instead of 1. However, when they reach 49 they restart at 1 again and ultimately throw a "unique constraint violation exception", as Id 31 is already used.

I checked the DB, there really exist "old" index (named e.g. SQL15082120153900). When the new entities are created a new index is added. The SEQUENCE table holds value "50" Which I wouldn't wanna change.

Any ideas, what causes this odd behaviour or how I can fix it? I wonder why the index is not dropped along with the table. Or at least the "index counter" or how it is called is reset. Very odd.

PS: we're running a tomcat with a local derby, however it also occurs on an embedded derby as well as a sybase ASE DB.

Comment: Set the allocation size to match the increment in the DB. See: http://royontechnology.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/note-on-allocationsize-parameter-of.html and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Invalid.2C_duplicate_or_negative_sequence_numbers.

Comment: I stumbled upon this solution as well, but I'm pretty sure this will collide with already existing DBs, which are never started with "drop-and-create" but with "create" only. Won't adding a new @SequenceGenerator to each entity break the old applications, as their DBs will still have the default sequence, while they have an annotation that tells them to use a different one?

Comment: New tables can use a new sequence object without affecting existing apps, but existing tables need to continue to use the same sequence or you will get conflicts.  Drop DDL is only meant for testing though, so I don't see why you would try to implement a workaround that would go into production.  What does the SQL EclipseLink uses show?  I don't see how a sequence would go up to 70 then reset to 31 without something else going on.

Comment: I now used the sequenceGenerator proposed by Alan and it seems to work. We didn't test yet against our test machine, which mimics productive behaviour, but everything else runs smoothly now, so I assume, that it's fine now...

And yes, we didn't wanna have the workaround in productive environment, which is why I asked for a better solution and it seems that changing allocation size is just what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, it works using allocation size 1. However, we just noticed, what this implies: Massive performance issues, due to JPA having to increase the sequence counter after every single insert operation. As we'll have lots of those, this is no option. Any other ideas?